# How to remove some charactors at the end of a string when the charactors meet a condition?

Tags: php, string

I have some strings, some end by a language code with a trailing slash(`"xx/",can be "fr/", or "en/", or other` ), some end by a number with trailing slash(`"int/", can be "2.0/" or "3.0/"`).

I want to remove the language code "xx/" if the string end with "xx/", and do nothing if end with "int/".

By `substr($sring, -3)`, I can identify what is the final. But how to remove it if the final is "xx/"?

Comment: Just a side note: `2.0` is not an int. In most languages 2/2.0 = 1.0, not 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = 'adfadsfasdfafasd asdf asdfasdf asdfr/';
$string = preg_replace('#[a-z]{2}/$#', '', $string); // case sensitive
$string = preg_replace('#[a-z]{2}/$#i', '', $string); // case insensitive
```

not tested